# The following code for minimizing a function returns a RuntimeWarning. Why?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have been learning optimization methods for a few days now. The following code that I wrote returned a `RuntimeWarning`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def func(a, x):
    return 1 + (x - 0.5) * a

def log_like(a, x):
    sum1 = 0 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum1 += np.log(func(a, x[i]))
    return sum1
    
def log_like_prime(a, x):
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum1 += (x[i] - 0.5) / (1 + (x[i] - 0.5) * a)
    return sum1

def log_like_prime2(a, x):
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum1 += -(x[i] - 0.5) ** 2.0 / (1 + (x[i] - 0.5) * a) ** 2.0
    return sum1

x = [0.89, 0.03, 0.50, 0.36, 0.49]
a = -1
a_opt = minimize(
    log_like, a, args=(x,), method="Newton-CG",
    jac=log_like_prime, hess=log_like_prime2
)
print(a_opt)
```

Returns the following error:

```
fun: array([0.03194467])
     jac: array([0.18690836])
 message: 'Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
    nfev: 21
    nhev: 1
     nit: 0
    njev: 21
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: array([-1.])
py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  sum1 += np.log(func(a, x[i]))
py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  sum1 += np.log(func(a, x[i]))
```

It should not be returning an invalid value as for the given values of `x = [0.89, 0.03, 0.50, 0.36, 0.49]`, no negative value must be returned by the function inside the logarithm part. I cannot understand why such a problem is there.

Comment: Are you sure you want to minimize the function instead of maximizing it? There's no local minimum for your choice of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial guess for `a`, -1, gives strictly positive values `func(a, x[i])` for all `i`.

However scipy's minimization algorithm changes the value of `a` (that's how it finds a better value). Here, it goes towards larger negative values, eventually resulting in negative values for `func(a, x[i])` and thus the log error.

To debug (I agree that scipy is not friendly here) try writing `np.seterr(all='raise')` at the beginning of your script, then the warning raised in the log will transform into an error, and typing `%debug% in the next ipython cell, you'll be able to check the value of` a`:

```
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py in fun_wrapped(x)
     68         def fun_wrapped(x):
     69             self.nfev += 1
---> 70             return fun(x, *args)
     71 
     72         def update_fun():

~/tmp.py in log_like(a)
     12     sum1 = 0
     13     for i in range(len(x)):
---> 14         sum1 += np.log(func(a, x[i]))
     15     return sum1
     16 

FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in log

In [21]: %debug
> /home/mathurin/tmp.py(14)log_like()
     12     sum1 = 0
     13     for i in range(len(x)):
---> 14         sum1 += np.log(func(a, x[i]))
     15     return sum1
     16 

ipdb> a
a = array([-2.7761329])
```